# Jest - Express Test

Tags: express, jestjs, nestjs

I have a controller for simple car buying/selling API which does this

```
async processCarSale(@Res() res: any) {
    if(carSaleService.sale()) {
        return res.status(201).send(<some-body>);
    }
    return res.status(204).send(<some-other-body>);
}
```

I am trying to test that the status code is set correct with a unit test. Googling and using SO I found example similar to this

```
const mockResponse = {
    status: jest.fn(),
    send: jest.fn()
}
const mockResponseSent = { send: jest.fn() };
mockResponse.status = jest.fn(() => mockResponseSent);

await carController.processCarSale(response);
expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
```

However this does not seem to actually test the status code.

Is there any way to test the statusCode sent in the response via Express?

Answer (score 2):

Your mock doesn't ever set a value called `statusCode`, it just stubs the functionality and returns the same object so that `send()` can be called as well (also a stub). If you want to be able to test something like `res.statusCode === 200` you could do something like this:

```js
const mockResponse = {
    status: jest.fn(),
    send: jest.fn(),
    statusCode: 0
}
const mockResponseSent = { send: jest.fn() };
mockResponse.status = jest.fn(() => {
  mockResponseSent.statusCode = 200;
  return mockResponseSent;
});

await carController.processCarSale(response);
expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
```

However, this is essentially jsut re-writing the logic of your controller in the first place, which isn't really good. So what would be better would be to take advanatage of Jest's `mockImplementation()` method where you can do

```js
const mockResponse = {
    status: jest.fn(),
    send: jest.fn()
}
const mockResponseSent = { send: jest.fn() };
mockResponse.status = jest.fn().mockImplementation((status) => {
  mockResponseSent.statusCode = status;
  return mockResponseSent;
});

await carController.processCarSale(response);
expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
```

Overall, though, I would suggest ditching the use of `res` in your controller and suggest letting Nest handle the setting of the http status code and sending the response. You can set the code to something other than default by using `@HttpCode()`

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) ([provided by default with Nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing)).

You can use the also provided HttpStatus enum which provides all HTTP code status.

```
test('/route (POST)', () => {
  const data = { any: 'data', what: 'you want' }
  request(app.getHttpServer())
            .post('/route')
            .send(data)
            .expect(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response; however with SuperTest its not really a unit test anymore

Comment: @RaySaudlach Controllers don't do that match (Bisnise logic wise) and they are cumbersome to mock. You should switch to `Integration-test` instead of `unit-test` for testing controllers. Save the mocking for services and utilities